# IntPtr Address increment (not value)

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling, intptr

I have a C++ DLL which has got functions to send data from a device. From my managed C# code i call the C++ function positionCallback. Here notice the pos. pos as per definition-is Array of three pointers, pointing to arrays of positions.

```
public void positionCallback(uint devNo,uint count,uint index,ref System.IntPtr pos,ref System.IntPtr mrk)
```

Now my issue is i want to extract the data of each of those 3 arrays but i can only get the data for Array 1 and for rest 2 i am getting garbage value.
Below is the code i am trying

```
 // Copy the unmanaged array to managed memory for Axis 2
IntPtr ptr2 = IntPtr.Add(pos,2*sizeof(Int64));
 Marshal.Copy(pos,managedArrayAxis1,0,(int)count);
 // Copy the unmanaged array to managed memory for Axis 2
 Marshal.Copy(ptr2, managedArrayAxis2, 0, (int)count);
```

Above code is giving correct data only for managedArrayAxis1 but for managedArrayAxis2, garbage data is collecting. Am i wrongly incrementing IntPtr address for pos?

Please help!

Comment: are you sure that Int64 is correct? If it should be int and you are using Int64, that would cause problems.

Comment: Int32 is also giving garbage values for managedArrayAxis2. So tried both stuff. Any other suggestion will help!

Comment: what about the fact that you are passing those pointers by reference. I would imagine that will look like int** to the c++ library. are you sure that is what the c++ method is looking for?

Comment: in c++ it looks like    static void positionCallback( unsigned int devNo, unsigned int count, unsigned int index,
                              const double * const pos[3], const bln32 * const mrk[3] ),  I am getting data for 1 set of Array but for other set i am getting garbage. Which looks like "pos" in pointing to correct array address but ptr2 is not able to point to correct location @pquest

Comment: why not use sizeof double?

Comment: Why have you not written the parameter as `IntPtr pos[]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `pos` parameter is actually a pointer to an array of pointers to double arrays so you need to dereference it twice. What's happening with your code is that the `ref` automatically dereferences the pointer to array of pointers but what you're getting in `pos` is just the first pointer out of 3 second level pointers and no way to get to the other two.

To get the original pointer you need to remove the `ref` keyword on `pos` parameter. Then copy the data pointed to by `pos` into an array of `IntPtr`s and you won't need any pointer arithmetic:

```
public void positionCallback(uint devNo,uint count,uint index,System.IntPtr pos,ref System.IntPtr mrk)

// copy the array of pointers
IntPtr[] arrays = new IntPtr[3];
Marshal.Copy(pos, arrays, 0, 3);

// Copy the unmanaged array to managed memory for Axis 2
Marshal.Copy(arrays[0],managedArrayAxis1,0,(int)count);

// Copy the unmanaged array to managed memory for Axis 2
Marshal.Copy(arrays[1], managedArrayAxis2, 0, (int)count);
```

Comment: @Ben, why "No"? You're exactly right, there are only two layers - top one is the array of `double *` which I copy into `arrays` with first `Marshal.Copy`. This allows me to access the 3 second layer arrays which I do with the other two `Marshal.Copy()` calls, which I've just copied from the question. What's your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your first sentence as a triple pointer.